# Import products for store view

Tags: import, store-view, magento-1.5, csv

I try to translate my product names in the new English store view and import changes, but when I import the csv, it override the default data.

```
sku,_store,name
31006,default,Небе
31006,en,Sky
```

After the import I can see in the Admin Panel that the "Use Default Value" checkbox is allays checked in the English store view.

I have also tried to specify the sku only 1 time and insert my modification right after it in a new row. This method is described [here](http://www.integer-net.de/download/ImportExport_EN.pdf).

```
sku,_store,name
31006,default,Небе
     ,en,Sky
```

The problem here is that there is an error - Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

I really can't understand my fault, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the store view should be specified in the Import/Export Profile>Profil Wizard>Profile Information>Store. So for each store view there should be also a different csv file.